# SlidingMenu: спрятать активити

Tags: android

Оттягивая активити1 вправо, выезжает активити 2, с помощью кнопочки хочу сделать чтобы активити 2 заезжало обратно и было видно только активити1. Знаю только, что активити 1 остается главным.. может какой то метод меня спасет?

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: Есть такой способ...:

В эклипсе вводите ИмяОбъекта. и жмёте cntr+пробел. Он предлагает различные методы. Какой из них подходит, можно определить по названию. Здесь наверняка должен быть какой-нибудь setPage

Comment: да это я знаю, просто думал что кто-нибудь подскажет этот самый метод) типо сетпейджа нету к сожалению

Comment: А именно активити должны быть? Фрагменты никак использовать не получится в этом случае?

Comment: getSlidingMenu().toggle(); если оно активно то оно закрывается 2 часа убил xD

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас google представил новый патерн для таких целей.

[Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

Используйте его.

Comment: спасибо большое, но именно то что я использую больше подходит =)

Comment: Обычно то, на что уходит 2 часа, соооовсем не охота переделывать